# foreach loop stops after first iteration

Tags: php, foreach

Trying to pull an id from an xml file, pass it into an api query, and load the results into a dom document. Thing is my `foreach` loop is only returning the first iteration, then seems to stop.

Why isn't it going back to fetch the next `PROGRAM_ID`?

```
//load results of first api call into simplexml - print_r here gives me a big array with all the expected rows in it
$progsitecontent = simplexml_load_file($progsiteapi);

//set which nodes to step through to reach required information
$totalprogsitecontent = $progsitecontent->matrix->rows->row;

//for each instance of a program id in this simplexml file:
foreach($totalprogsitecontent->PROGRAM_ID as $progid)
{

    //...substitute the program id into the api call
    $programdetails = $progdetailsapi_start.$progid.$progdetailsapi_end;
    $complete_program_details = simplexml_load_file($programdetails);

    //now for each instance of a programs info, load into a DOM document and carry out the below actions - from here down already works in another script so im sure the problem has to be above this point 

    $prog_info = $complete_program_details->matrix->rows->row;

    //create the top line container tag
    $row = $doc->createElement ("programInformation");

    //create the container tag
    $progID = $doc->createElement("programId");
    //fill it with the information you want
    $progID->appendChild ( $doc->createTextNode ( $prog_info->PROGRAM_ID ) );
    //attach this information to the row
    $row->appendChild($progID);

    //repeat for each element you want to include
    $progName = $doc->createElement("programName");
    $progName->appendChild ( $doc->createTextNode ( $prog_info->PROGRAM_NAME ) );
    $row->appendChild($progName);

    $progURLs = $doc->createElement("programUrls");
    $progURLs->appendChild ( $doc->createTextNode ( $prog_info->PROGRAM_URLS ) );
    $row->appendChild($progURLs);

    $progLogo = $doc->createElement("programLogo");
    $progLogo->appendChild ( $doc->createTextNode ( $prog_info->MERCHANT_LOGO ) );
    $row->appendChild($progLogo);

    $r->appendChild ($row);

}

echo $doc->saveXML();
```

Feel free to comment on how any of this has been written. I'm still at the stage of "bodge-it-and-see" :)

Comment: What is the result of `$totalprogsitecontent`?

Comment: post the xml part for $totalprogsitecontent

Comment: is `$totalprogsitecontent->PROGRAM_ID` an array?

Comment: I've changed this slightly, so $totalprogsitecontent has become $progsitecontent. A print_r of $progsitecontent gives me a big array, not xml.

Comment: didnt mean to press return there......back in a few mins with the xml

Comment: $progsitecontent is $progsiteid loaded into simple xml. a sample of the $progsiteid xml is:

<matrix rowcount="985">
<columns>
<PROGRAM_ID type="string">PROGRAM_ID</PROGRAM_ID>
<AFFILIATE_ID type="string">AFFILIATE_ID</AFFILIATE_ID>
</columns>
<rows>
<row>
<PROGRAM_ID>137</PROGRAM_ID>
<AFFILIATE_ID>1291517</AFFILIATE_ID>
</row>
<row>
<PROGRAM_ID>170</PROGRAM_ID>
<AFFILIATE_ID>1291517</AFFILIATE_ID>
</row>
<row>
<PROGRAM_ID>193</PROGRAM_ID>
<AFFILIATE_ID>1291517</AFFILIATE_ID>
</row>

Comment: Array:
 [matrix] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [rowcount] => 985 ) [columns] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [PROGRAM_ID] => PROGRAM_ID [AFFILIATE_ID] => AFFILIATE_ID ) [rows] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [row] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [PROGRAM_ID] => 137 [AFFILIATE_ID] => 1291517 ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [PROGRAM_ID] => 170 [AFFILIATE_ID] => 1291517 ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [PROGRAM_ID] => 193 [AFFILIATE_ID] => 1291517 )
and so on.....

Answer (score 1):

Can't say much without seeing the full result of `$totalprogsitecontent`, but I think it should look something like this:

```
foreach($totalprogsitecontent as $progid)
{
...
}
```

Since `$totalprogsitecontent->PROGRAM_ID` is already a single value - so you're iterating over this element instead of the array.

Also, your `$progid` is lowercase in the for loop but you refer to `$progID` -- PHP is case sensitive.

---

After looking at your XML code here's what it should look like.

```
foreach($progsitecontent->matrix->rows->row as $row){
     $progid = $row['PROGRAM_ID'];
     $affid = $row['AFFILIATE_ID'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the notes. I've changed the variables to be the same case, but removing the ->matrix->rows->row->PROGRAM_ID has stopped it from returning even the first iteration

Comment: Hi Nick, that sorted it, thanks!
The problem was that I was drilling down one node too far in the xml.
I was going for each piece of data under matrix->rows->row->programID
What I actually wanted was to go for each piece of data under matrix->rows->row then grab the detail from the $row object

Cheers